# Image analysis for crowdedness

Tags: image, image-processing, face-detection

I am want to writing a program that could analyse a static image to detect how many people are there. Windows platform. Language .NET, Java or Python. Any existing open source project or any library that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the library [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) that has a lot of bindings to different platsforms/languages. Here is one simple example using Python to detect faces in an image: https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-recognition-with-python/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will evaluate it's performance.